# Website linking title - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Could someone point out how to get the white space left to the login box to be highlighted as part of the link in the title heading?  Obviously I don want people to click on the login box and get linked back to the homepage.  Tried floating the loginBox element and really not sure what to do. Here's the code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <a href="#" style="display:block">
                <div id="title">
                <h1>Record Store</h1>
                <img src="images/vinyl.jpg" height="80px" width="auto" />
                </div>
            </a>

                <div id="loginBox">
                    <form action="#">
                        <label>User Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>Password: </label>
                        <input type="password" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </form>
                </div>  

            <div id="navigation" >
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vinyl Stock</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Online Offers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Collectors News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>You'd be a fool to believe anything on this site</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <span id="adminLogin"><a href="#">Admin Login</a></span>
                <p id="copyright">&copy;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
* {
        padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
}

h1{
    font: bold 2.8em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    position:absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top:5px;

}

img { 
    position: absolute;
    left:300px;
    /*top:5px;*/

    }


#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -9;
}

#title {

    margin:auto;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    height: 16%;
    position: relative;
}

#loginBox{
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation{
    clear:both;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

#content{
    min-height:400px;
    background-color: white;
}

#adminLogin{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#footer{
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#copyright{
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;

}




.navbar {

}

.navbar ul {

}


.navbar li {

    font: bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1% 0px;



}
.navbar a {
    border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.navbar li:hover a {
    color: black;

}

.navbar li:hover{
    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle out of this? So we can see what it looks like.

Comment: First attempt at using JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4vUr/.  Doesn't look well in IE.

Comment: You could either add a `z-index` to your form so the form sits on top of the link to the homepage, or make your whole container wider so it all fits next to each other. Why is your container 800px wide anyway?

Comment: FYI - DIVs shouldn't be used within a <a> tag. Use span's instead, set as display:block. If you're looking to be w3c compliant.

Comment: I'm wanting the login box to sit at the bottom right of the title.

Comment: Might rethink the title layout completely now

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to fill a parent div with your anchor, and then absolutely position the login on top. The absolutely positioned header and image are better placed using padding, to maintain the box's natural height.

```
h1 {
    font: bold 2.8em Arial,Verdana,Helvetica;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
}
#title {
    padding: 5px 0 24px 10px;
}
#loginBox{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

And then add your relative div, like

```
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" style="display:block">
            <div id="title">
            <h1>Record Store</h1>
            <img src="images/vinyl.jpg" height="80px" width="auto" />
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="loginBox">
            <form action="#">
                <label>User Name: </label>
                <input type="text" />
                <label>Password: </label>
                <input type="password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
```